# returning function instead of value

Tags: javascript, lodash

im tring to format some values and also creating a if statement in case that the value is null, but is returning me a function instead of a value.

Here is my code:

```
var data = _.map(information).map(function(x) {
  return _.assign(x, {
    age: function() {
      if (x.age != null) {
        x.age.toString();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: If you want chaining lodash methods, use sintaxis like this: `_(arr).map(function() {...}).value()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke your function inline if you want to get the result (and don't forget to add `return`):

```
age: (function() {
    if (x.age != null) {
        return x.age.toString();
    }
})()
```

However you don't need a function to check if value isn't null. You can write a boolean expression:

```
age: x.age && x.age.toString()
```

or use a ternary operator:

```
age: x.age ? x.age.toString() : undefined
```